# My Firebase count method is not working correctly

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase to count the number of adverts each individual user watches. This part works fine, then when the user has watched 5 adverts it unlocks customizations to the app. This is my code for counting the users adverts

```
public void count() {

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    uID = user.getUid();

    ref = mrootRef.child("dowload_counters").child("Adverts_Watched").getRef();
    ref.child("counter").child(uID).runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
        @Override
        public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {

            if (mutableData.getValue() == null) {
                mutableData.setValue(1);
            } else {

//here I grab the int to use with my rewards, I think it could be something here causing the problem??
               count = mutableData.getValue(Integer.class);
                mutableData.setValue(count + 1);
            }


            return Transaction.success(mutableData);


        }
```

This is my rewards method:

```
public void Rewards_Stuff(Context c){

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    uID = user.getUid();
    ref = mrootRef.child("RewardsSystem").getRef();

    if (count<5) {

//this one works and registers to my database
        Toast.makeText(c,"watch more ads to gain reward points",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        ref.child("counter").child(uID).setValue("0");

    }else
    if (count==5){

//this one won't?
        Toast.makeText(c,"New button colours unlocked from the main menu",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ref.child("counter").setValue("1");
    }else
    if (count>5 && count<10) {

//this one won't?
        Toast.makeText(c, "Thanks for the on going support gain more reward points by watching adverts", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ref.child("counter").child(uID).setValue("1");
    }else
    if (count==10){
        Toast.makeText(c,"background unlocked from main menu",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ref.child("counter").setValue("2");
    }
}
```

Why isn't it grabbing the value of count correctly?

Comment: Do your security rules allow writing to `/counter`?  The write that succeeds is to `/counter/$uid`.  The two that fail are to `/counter`.  Post your rules.

Comment: it does allow write to counter. as it writes the first value 0 no problem. ive watched in real time as it writes the user id and the value 0.

Comment: But the rules could allow a write to `/counter/$uid` and forbid one to `/counter`. Add a `CompletionListener` to `setValue()` to see why it's failing.

Comment: In the second piece of code you use `count`, which you never seem to initialize. How do these two pieces of code relate? I recommend reproducing the problem in a separate app, so you can isolate the problematic code from the rest of the app. Read more about [why creating an MCVE is useful](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).